# Como cruzar informações de colunas para ver se são verdadeiras no R?

Tags: banco-de-dados, r, if

Estou com uma dúvida na criação de um script que averigue as informações preenchidas no banco de dados.

Basicamente eu tenho duas colunas: "SEXO" e "GESTANTE". A coluna "Sexo" é preenchida com "M" ou "F", masculino e feminino, respectivamente. A coluna "Gestante" é preenchida com 7 números (1,2,3,4,5,6 e 9) que se referem à: "1 - 1º Trimestre", "2 - 2º Trimestre", "3 - 3º trimestre", "4 - Idade ignorada", " 5 - Não ", " 6 - Não se aplica ", "9 - Ignorado".

Basicamente eu preciso confirmar se as pessoas do sexo "Masculino" constam dentre as opções "5,6 e 9", e as pessoas do sexo "Feminino" estão assinaram as opções "1,2,3,4 ou 9"

tentei fazer o código utilizando o IF ELSE, mas sem sucesso.

```
if (DADOS_COMPLETO$CS_SEXO == "F"
            else DADOS_COMPLETO$CS_GESTANT == "1","2","3","4","9")
  
  sexox <- FALSE

if (DADOS_COMPLETO$CS_SEXO=="M"
    else DADOS_COMPLETO$CS_GESTANT=="5", "6", "9")
```

[image: Essa imagem é um recorte do banco de dados]

Por fim, traria uma nova coluna com as informações se TRUE ou se FALSE.

Comment: Imagens não são uma boa maneira de por dados, veja este [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Pode, por favor, [editar a pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/63437490/edit) com a saída de `dput(DADOS_COMPLETO)` ou, se a base for muito grande, de `dput(head(DADOS_COMPLETO, 20))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O ideal seria você disponibilizar uma amostra reproduzível dos seus dados como mencionou o @Rui Barradas

Mas segue aqui uma sugestão:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Construindo uma amostra:

```
dados_completos <- tibble(sexo = c("M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F"),
                          gestant = c(1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 5, 15, 7, 6))
```

Em seguida é possível aplicar a função `case_when()` em combinação com a função `mutate()`.

Assim, cria-se uma nova variável chamada `resultado` cuja lógica é a seguinte:

- se **sexo** for igual a **M** *e* **gestant** for **5,6 ou 9**, atribuir `(~)` o termo "CORRETO",
- se **sexo** for igual a **F** *e* **gestant** estiver compreendido entre **1 e 4, ou for o número 9**, atribuir `(~)`o termo "CORRETO",
- em todos os outros casos, atribuir `(~)` o termo "INCORRETO"

```
dados_completos %>% 
  mutate(resultado = case_when(sexo == "M" & gestant %in% c(5,6,9) ~ "CORRETO",
                               sexo == "F" & gestant %in% c(1:4,9) ~ "CORRETO",
                               TRUE ~ "INCORRETO"))
```

Resultado:

```
# A tibble: 9 × 3
  sexo  gestant resultado
  <chr>   <dbl> <chr>    
1 M           1 INCORRETO
2 F           2 CORRETO  
3 M           3 INCORRETO
4 M           6 CORRETO  
5 F           9 CORRETO  
6 M           5 CORRETO  
7 M          15 INCORRETO
8 M           7 INCORRETO
9 F           6 INCORRETO
```

Answer (score 2):

Se a coluna indicando sexo tem apenas dois valores, pode usar `ifelse` e operador `%in%` para marcar TRUE/FALSE:

```
# Dados de exemplo
set.seed(57)
dados <- data.frame(
  sexo = rep(c("F", "M"), each = 4),
  gestante = sample(c(1:6,9), 8, TRUE))

dados$preenchimento_correto <- with(dados,
  ifelse(sexo == "F", gestante %in% c(1:4,9), gestante %in% c(5:6,9))
)
```

Traduzindo: "se sexo for F, marcar na coluna 'preenchimento_correto' TRUE se gestante for 1, 2, 3, 4 ou 9, caso contrário (sexo M), marcar TRUE se gestante for 5, 6 ou 9". O resultado:

```
dados
#>   sexo gestante preenchimento_correto
#> 1    F        2                  TRUE
#> 2    F        4                  TRUE
#> 3    F        1                  TRUE
#> 4    F        2                  TRUE
#> 5    M        6                  TRUE
#> 6    M        5                  TRUE
#> 7    M        9                  TRUE
#> 8    M        3                 FALSE
```

Comment: Carlos Eduardo Lagosta vc tem repositorio no github?

Comment: @itamar, tenho, mas quase nunca uso: usuário `olagosta`